# Apex - application static files not found

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have installed recently Apex 19.2

Apex works fine, however my applications don't show any static application files.

I uploaded an image to my workspace app and I insert it in a region as follows :

```
<img src="#APP_IMAGES#Logo.png" />
```

When the page loads, the substitution string is parsed and I have an error :

9#GET https://www.example.com:8080/ords/useralias/r/100/files/static/v2/Logo.png 404 (Not Found)

I tried this but it's not working

```
@apex_epg_config.sql C:\My\01-Tools\04-Apex  (Apex home)
```

Also here is my standalone.properties file :

```
jetty.secure.port=8080
standalone.context.path=/ords
standalone.doc.root=C\:\\My\\01-Tools\\03-Ords Installation\\ords\\standalone\\doc_root
standalone.scheme.do.not.prompt=true
standalone.static.context.path=/i
standalone.static.path=C\:\\My\\01-Tools\\04-Apex\\apex\\images
ssl.cert=C\:\\My\\01-Tools\\03-Ords Installation\\ords\\standalone\\certificate\\certificate.der
ssl.cert.key=C\:\\My\\01-Tools\\03-Ords Installation\\ords\\standalone\\certificate\\private.der
ssl.host=www.example.com
```

All the paths are correct.

Does any know how to solve that please ?

Thanks
Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you updating apex and using ords? If so, executing this command might solve your problem.

```
java -jar ords.war validate
```

this validates the instalation and the static files.